# How can you detect a unique value in an exe using Java?

Tags: java, list, process, hex, exe

I've got this going at the moment;

```
                public class ProcessKill {
                private static final String TASKLIST = "tasklist";
                private static final String KILL = "taskkill /IM ";

                public static boolean isProcessRunging(String serviceName) throws Exception {
                 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(TASKLIST);
                 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                 p.getInputStream()));

                 String line;

                 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                     System.out.println(line);

                     if (line.contains(serviceName)){
                         return true;
                     }
                 }

                 return false;

                }

                public static void killProcess(String serviceName) throws Exception {

                  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(KILL + serviceName);

                 }  


            }

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    ProcessKill pkill = new ProcessKill();
    String processName = "wmplayer.exe";

    if (pkill.isProcessRunging(processName)){
        pkill.killProcess(processName);
    }

}
```

Only problem is, what if the name is changed? I don't want to keep updating the code. Is there a way to grab a hex value of an .exe file and read it into Java for it to detect that instead?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly would you like to grab? Your code is just killing task by name and I personally do not understand what does the phrase "what if the same is changed?" means. Same what? The same process? The same executable?

Comment: Sorry, typo. That was meant to and now says "name".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, you can first check if the process you want to kill is running by executing `wmic.exe PROCESS where name='"+processName+"'` - although WMIC provides a PROCESS DELETE option, the java-process blocks when calling this. `wmic PROCESS` (without any specifig process name) returns a list (and description) of all currently running processes on a windows machine which you can read in using an `InputSreamReader()` and then iterate through all running processes and check which of these might be your target process. Moreover the line of your target process contains arguments passed to your process which you can either use to distinguish processes in case you have multiple processes running or need to delete some resource files your application used.

While debugging our application which uses an embedded mongodb for unit-tests, after debugging the embedded mongod process kept running and refused to work on the next unit-test (as the unit-test cleanup was not executed properly) - furthermore it created a local datastore which could not be overridden by a new embedded mongod process - so it needed to get deleted manually. I therefore extracted the file from the line returned by WMIC and deleted the files after killing the process automatically.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you do not want to hold the process name hard-coded. In this case just pass it through command line parameters:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    ProcessKill pkill = new ProcessKill();
    String processName = args[0];

    if (pkill.isProcessRunging(processName)){
        pkill.killProcess(processName);
    }

}
```

Now your user has to provide the process name to kill in command line:

`:> ProcessKill notepad.exe`

However IMHO I do not understand why do you need your utility at all? Indeed you just run `processkill`, so user can use it directly. Your utility does not provide any additional functionality.